# Using WifiManager.startScan()

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifimanager

after WifiManager.startScan() use it yields different values after every 6 seconds. How to force it to get new values of scan sooner? I really need to get new result as soon as possible, ideally every 10ms.
Is it possible somehow? At this moment, I´m using this code:

```
wifi.startScan();
    vysledek = wifi.getScanResults();
    int sizeList = vysledek.size();
    for (int a = 0; a < sizeList; a++) {
        // porovnani vysledku s pripojenou ssid//
        if (vysledek.get(a).SSID.equalsIgnoreCase(ssid)) 
        {
            tw5.setText(vysledek.get(a).SSID);
            tw6.setText(vysledek.get(a).BSSID);
            tw7.setText(String.valueOf(vysledek.get(a).level));
            tw8.setText(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        }
    }

    sleep();

    wifi.startScan();
    vysledek = wifi.getScanResults();
    sizeList = vysledek.size();
    for (int a = 0; a < sizeList; a++) {
        // porovnani vysledku s pripojenou ssid//
        if (vysledek.get(a).SSID.equalsIgnoreCase(ssid)) 
        {
            tw9.setText(vysledek.get(a).SSID);
            tw10.setText(vysledek.get(a).BSSID);
            tw11.setText(String.valueOf(vysledek.get(a).level));
            tw12.setText(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        }
    }

    sleep();
```

Where sleep(); is:

```
public void sleep()
    {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Output now is:
[image]

as you can see, I call wifi.startScan(); everytime I want to get new results but it gives me same results as before until 6 seconds is gone. After 6 seconds signal level value changes.
Please help me with that :) Thanks

Comment: I haven't yet work on it, but there should be any way to set the listener or register the broadcast receiver for the wi-fi states same like in Bluetooth.

Comment: Yes, you can use broadcast receiver but it doesnt solve my issues. Even with receiver it changes scanned value every 6 seconds which is so much for my needs

Comment: Did you want to see the signal strength changed of wi-fi or for any new network?

Comment: Its for wifi. But because of signal strength of wifi networks fluctuate I need to measure it and get as many samples as I can. I dont care about other networks